# Default value for input box not showing up

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

I have input:

```
@Html.TextBox("dateFrom", null, new { data_bind="value:StartDateTemp", type = "datetime", @class = "form-control datepicker", required = "required ",@Value=DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() })
```

this renders into:

```
<input value="2014-03-19" class="form-control datepicker" data-bind="value:StartDateTemp" id="dateFrom" name="dateFrom" required="required " type="datetime">
```

As you can see I'm populating input with Current time and its bind to StartDateTemp.

Beside we can see value in code the Field stays empty. Can anyone suggest edits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be because your data-bind="value:StartDateTemp" returns empty.

just remove that attribute and check.

```
@Html.TextBox("dateFrom", null, new {type = "datetime", @class = "form-control datepicker", required = "required ",@Value=DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() })
```

**Edit:**

You make sure whether you get the value for the `StartDateTemp` where you are binding using knockout. `data-bind="value:StartDateTemp"`

Comment: Yeah now it's working but now my `KnockoutJS` bind is not working